# How can I change the visibility of setter method by Intellij code generator?

Tags: intellij-idea, getter-setter, generated-code

In my code generator, I saw the default visibility is public, so all methods generated is public, although I customized myself template of setter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7FZ.png)

My template:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZZV.png)
Now, I need public getter and protected setter. How can I do?

Comment: add code instead of images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't, I'm afraid.

Like the text at the bottom of IDEA's "Customize Template" dialog says:

"Visibility is applied according to File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation".

That setting does not distinguish between getters and setters, unfortunately.

You can always create a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: What a bummer… :-(